# How to accelerate the landing web page using Django on Digitalocean?

Tags: django, nginx, digital-ocean, production

I created a "landing page website" using Django, it's a very simple website for using just for showing up the data with no query sets that coming from the database it's just 3 or 4 queries.

I'm using the Nginx server for deploying and everything working properly but just the loading of the page is very very slow, I don't know where can I find the issue. I thought that the problem might become from Nginx since it has the ability to manage static files and also, I thought about maybe droplet cause such that issue.

my brain is frozen about finding the core of that problem where I can't think of where the problem may happen so, how can I accelerate my web page, and what are the reasons for that problem?

I don't know if StackOverflow is a good choice to ask such that question or not but I will be grateful for solving that problem in advance

Comment: Do you load big picture ? Or external js/css type references synchronously... which could slow down the loading? Have you looked in the debugging console of your browser to see the loading time of your files?

Comment: yes, there are some images are loaded on the page but this loading takes no time in the case of the localhost compared with digital-ocean where take a lot of time to end the request

Comment: If the problem comes from the images you can try to reduce their quality. Or you can do a two-step load, pre-load the page with the low quality images, load the high quality images in the background and load them in the view once downloaded

Comment: Ensure that django `DEBUG` setting is set to `False` in your server and test your page with https://pagespeed.web.dev/, in order to know the real problem.